# what does ownership mean in lock based synchronizing method of shared resources?

Tags: operating-system

Imagine if one thread owns the lock, can't we change the lock variable to 1(available) at some point of our code (lock->available = 1) in another thread ? if so why we say "The owner for calls to lock and unlock must be the same thread."

Comment: It means 'possession of the lock'.

Comment: Thank you, but imagine if one thread owns the lock, can't we change the lock variable to 1(available) at some point of our code (lock->available = 1) in another thread ? if so it contradicts with the statement "The owner for calls to lock and unlock must be the same thread."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say "owner", it's more of a concept and contract that we adhere to than physical guarantees.

With locks, we say there is an acquisition process that yields an owner. That owner is the only thread able to do something controlled by the lock, and it is the only thread that can release the lock once it's done, at which point it is no longer the owner.

From a hardware perspective, there's nothing guaranteeing this, as you've pointed out.  However, these are fairly useful properties for many reasons, so we typically encapsulate them in an opaque api as a mutex, which provides the expected behaviour while not allowing a cooperative programmer to break the abstraction of ownership.

There is some movement in more recent hardware towards transactional memory, which comes closer to your ideal of one thread not being able to unlock a lock it doesn't own.